# string concatenation order in fold function

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to understand the following problem :
I've defined a list and i'm using fold function on this list for concatenating  these strings.

with `foldr`

```
food = ["Pizza", "Apple", "Banana"]
let f = (\a b -> take 3 a ++ b)
foldr f "" food
-- result
"PizAppBan"
```

whilst with the `foldl`

```
food = ["Pizza", "Apple", "Banana"]
    let f = (\a b -> take 3 a ++ b)
    foldr f "" food
    -- result
    "BanAppPiz"
```

So i understood that the order change because, wherease we are doing some commutative operation the order does not important...for string concatenation instead is.
so the question is how in fold left the string concatenation is evaluated and how i can visualize conceptually the operation order?because if i take step by step the following operation, the process would result always the same...

ps. I've seen that there is just some qestions about that but they not seem much clear regarding how the process work.

Comment: The parameters are "flipped". In the `foldr`, the "accumulator" is the second element, whereas in the `foldl` it is the first.

Answer (score 0):

The order of the parameters of the folding function are "flipped". Indeed, if we look at the defintions for `foldl` and `foldr` we see:

```
foldl :: Foldable t => (b -> a -> b) -> b -> t a -> b
foldr :: Foldable t => (a -> b -> b) -> b -> t a -> b
```

Here in both definitions the "accumulator" has a type `b`. But as you can see, in the `foldl` function, the fold function has type `b -> a -> b`, so the first parameter is the accumulator, the second the element, and it returns a new value for the accumulator. This to illustrate that the folding goes left-to-right.

For the `foldr` function the fold function has type `a -> b -> b`, so first it takes an element, next it takes the value for the accumulator after folding the rest of the list, and you should return the new value for the accumulator. It thus folds right-to-left.

If you want to let this work for `foldl`, you thus take `\b a -> …` with `b` the accumulator. In that case you return `b ++ take a 3`, so we append the first three characters of `a` at the right end of the accumulator:

```
Prelude> foldr (\a b -> take 3 a ++ b) "" ["Pizza", "Apple", "Banana"]
"PizAppBan"
Prelude> foldl (\b a -> b ++ take 3 a) "" ["Pizza", "Apple", "Banana"]
"PizAppBan"
```

Flipping the parameters is thus not enough. Evaluation is done from left-to-right in case of `foldl` and right-to-left in case of `foldr`, this thus means that you also need to swap the way you concatenate.

The `foldl` variant will however be less efficient here, since the [**`(++) :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]`** function](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-43--43-) takes time linear in the length of the first operand.

The function `\a b -> take 3 a ++ b`, is not *commutative*, nor is it *associative*. Indeed, commutative means that `f x y` is equal to `f y x` for each `x` and `y`. But if we call `f "foobar" "qux"` we retrieve:

```
Prelude> f "foobar" "qux"
"fooqux"
Prelude> f "qux" "foobar"
"quxfoobar"
```

The concat operation `(++)` is not commutative either.

Furthermore the opperation is not *associative* either, because of the `take 3` part. Indeed, an associative operation means that `f x (f y z)` is equal to `f (f x y) z` for each `x`, `y` and `z`. But we see:

```
Prelude> f (f "foo" "bar") "qux"
"fooqux"
Prelude> f "foo" (f "bar" "qux")
"foobarqux"
```

If you however first perform a `map` to take the first three characters of each string, then indeed the order does not matter:

```
Prelude> foldl (++) "" (map (take 3) food)
"PizAppBan"
Prelude> foldr (++) "" (map (take 3) food)
"PizAppBan"
```

The `take 3` part thus makes the function *non-associative*, and therefore you can not use it in both `foldl` and `foldr` without adapting it properly.

Comment: Hi! thanks for answering yes but in my case the `foldl` return **"BanAppPizz"** and `foldr` return **"PizzAppBan"** ....i did not understand this....in practice what happen inside the function? are you able to show me the process? because if i think this on paper i get to the same point : `foldr->("Ban" ++ ("App" ++ ( "Pizz"++ "" )))` and
foldl->`((((""++"Ban")++"App")++"Pizz")` ....so both would seem the same...what i wrong?

Comment: @Markus: you use `take 3`, that is not only on the values of the *parameter*, but also on the intermediate results, so for `foldl`, it will be `take 3 (take 3 (take 3 "" ++ "Pizza") ++ "Apple") ++ "Banana"`, as a result, after the second "iteration", you each time only retain the first three characters, so all the rest is removed again.

Comment: @Markus: note thtat your function is however not commutative (`(++)` is not commutative either, since `("foo" ++ "bar") != ("bar" ++ "foo")`), but more importantly, it is not *associative* either.

Comment: `take 3 (take 3 (take 3 "" ++ "Pizza") ++ "Apple") ++ "Banana"`.... ok but why `foldl` flip the result? as you have written...the order is the same except for the order esecution process...but if i wrote only  `(((""++"Ban" )++ "App")++ "Piz")` or  `("Ban" ++ ("App" ++ ( "Piz"++ "" )))` ... the order remain always the same.....Why???

Comment: @Markus: since it goes left to right, it makes more sense to first specify the accumulator, and then the element. But regardless, it is not only about flipping the result. Since your function is *not* associative. It means that the order of execution matters. Only for *associative* functions, like `(++)` it does not matter.

Comment: @Markus: note that for your function, `f (f "foo" "bar") "qux"` is not the same as `f "foo" (f "bar" "qux")`, hence that means that the order of execution has impact. You need to proof the associativity of the operator, but here that will fail.